# How can I get extra space in /boot partition to update linux kernel version in a QEMU VM?

Tags: kernel, qemu

I have an Ubuntu 16.10 Server LTS running in QEMU and I am trying to compile a new kernel version linux-4.13.8, more specifically.

Because I used default installation configurations, the partitions in thehh drive on QEMU are as follows:

[Partitions on qemu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTR1B.png)

I have downloaded and compiled the kernel version 4.13.8 by using the following commands:

`make && make modules && sudo make modules_install`

However, when I execute `sudo make install` I got the error about no space left on device, and off course it makes sense because in my host machine I am running this kernel version, and it shows that the initrd.img-4.13.8 file has 369MB in size.

So, I wonder how can I extend the `/boot/` partition size in this case, because I cannot use `gparted` I think.

***UPDATE***

Here is the contents in `/boot` partition

[/boot partition contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4K8m.png)

Comment: How many old kernels do you have in /boot ? Please list the content of /boot in your question.

Comment: Remove old kernels or use gparted from an iso

Comment: Also strip your modules https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.os.linux.development.system/bjU7AfeZl5I

Comment: I added @SorenA, please check it in the UPDATE part

Comment: 16.10 reached end-of-life in July 2017, and is no longer supported on this site. Please upgrade to 17.10.

Comment: Hello @ChaiT.Rex, thank you for reply but I don't think the Ubuntu version is the problem for this case.